# CSS Styling (Text, and paragraph backgrounds)

Tags: html, css, styling

I wish to create a site that displays paragraphs of my information with say a white background, and I want the paragraph background to be black, but with a low opacity as to clearly distinguish it from the rest with a different color and 100% opacity for the text I'm displaying. I can't seem to figure out how to do this however.

So far I've tried to change the background of the entire document to a light blue, change the text to white and change the paragraph background to black and lower the opacity. The background color changed as did the text however the paragraph background didn't show up at all. Even after I had deleted the opacity value to make sure I wasn't just making the opacity too low. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could solve this. I'd greatly appreciate all the help you have to offer me.

> body{   background:#00FFFF;   font-family:arial; } p{
>     background:#000000; } div{  color:white; }

Div is wrapped around my text inside of the paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it rightly, you want to have slightly darker background for some paragraphs. You can include opacity into the background using rgba function:

```css
body{ background:#00FFFF;  font-family:arial; } 
p{ background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); color:white}
```

```html
<p>
    my text
</p>
```

Comment: @Kurrel You are welcome! Good luck with your site :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `<div>` inside a `<p>` as this is not valid - both are block level elements. You can use a `<span>` instead which is an inline element.
For further information you can have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P

Example for illustration:

```css
body {
    background:#00FFFF;
    font-family:arial;
}
p {
    background:#000000;
}
div, span {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>This is a paragraph inside a div.</p>
</div>
<p>
    <div>This is a div inside a paragraph which is not valid.</div>
</p>
<p> <span>This is a span inside a paragraph which is fine.</span>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/uh632aL4/

The tick is to use `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);` for the div element.
In this way your text will have 100% opacity and you can change the opacity of div element as you wish.